# Make NameValueCollection accessible to LINQ Query

Tags: .net, linq, namevaluecollection

How to make `NameValueCollection` accessible to LINQ query operator such as where, join, groupby?

I tried the below:

```
private NameValueCollection RequestFields()
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection()
                                  {
                                      {"emailOption: blah Blah", "true"},
                                      {"emailOption: blah Blah2", "false"},
                                      {"nothing", "false"},
                                      {"nothinger", "true"}
                                  };
    return nvc;

}

public void GetSelectedEmail()
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = RequestFields();
    IQueryable queryable = nvc.AsQueryable();
}
```

But I got an *ArgumentException* telling me that the **source is not IEnumerable<>**.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065928/c-sharp-iterate-through-namevaluecollection/5066541#5066541

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You need to "lift" the non-generic `IEnumerable` to an `IEnumerable<string>`. It has been suggested that you use `OfType` but that is a filtering method. What you're doing is the equivalent of a cast, for which there is the `Cast` operator:

```
var fields = RequestFields().Cast<string>();
```

As Frans pointed out, this only provides access to the keys. You would still need to index into the collection for the values. Here is an extension method to extract `KeyValuePair`s from the `NameValueCollection`:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ToPairs(this NameValueCollection collection)
{
    if(collection == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    }

    return collection.Cast<string>().Select(key => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, collection[key]));
}
```

**Edit:** In response to @Ruben Bartelink's request, here is how to access the full set of values for each key using `ToLookup`:

```
public static ILookup<string, string> ToLookup(this NameValueCollection collection)
{
    if(collection == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    }

    var pairs =
        from key in collection.Cast<String>()
        from value in collection.GetValues(key)
        select new { key, value };

    return pairs.ToLookup(pair => pair.key, pair => pair.value);
}
```

Alternatively, using C# 7.0 tuples:

```
public static IEnumerable<(String name, String value)> ToTuples(this NameValueCollection collection)
{
    if(collection == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    }

    return
        from key in collection.Cast<string>()
        from value in collection.GetValues(key)
        select (key, value);
}
```

Comment: how can you use Where clause? and lambda?

Comment: @user384080: `RequestFields().ToPairs().Where(pair => pair.Key.Contains("a"))`

Comment: Warning. You can miss some values this way. One key can have multiple values assigned see method GetValues.

Comment: @Kugel: Great distinction - I did not realize that `NameValueCollection` actually supports multiple values per key. The documentation for the `Item` property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb.aspx) says it will return the values in a comma-separated list. So, you wouldn't lose them entirely, but they would not be in the key/value format that you might expect.

Comment: -1 Any chance of fixing the code to use `.ToLookup` or yielding arrays or adding an edit flagging the comma-separated list issue. Will remove when fixed and I see this again. (Just find it annoying that every answer here has bad advice as of this writing)

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink: I updated the answer to include a `.ToLookup` extension to `NameValueCollection` in case you need access to the full set of values for each key. Let me know if that meets your needs.

Comment: the Linq expression in `ToLookup` can be written as `collection.Cast<string>().SelectMany(key => collection.GetValues(key), (key, value) => new {key, value})`. If you want lambdas :)

Answer (score 12):

I know I'm late to the party but just wanted to add my answer that doesn't involve the `.Cast` extension method but instead uses the AllKeys property:

```
var fields = RequestFields().AllKeys;
```

This would allow the following extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ToPairs(this NameValueCollection collection)
{
    if(collection == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    }

    return collection.AllKeys.Select(key => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, collection[key]));
}
```

Hope this helps any future visitors

Comment: This looks like a decent way of implementing it. +1 for use

Answer (score 11):

`AsQueryable` must take an `IEnumerable<T>`, a generic. `NameValueCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, which is different.

Instead of this:

```
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = RequestFields();
    IQueryable queryable = nvc.AsQueryable();
}
```

Try [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) (it accepts the non-generic interface)

```
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = RequestFields();
    IEnumerable<string> canBeQueried = nvc.OfType<string>();
    IEnumerable<string> query =
       canBeQueried.Where(s => s.StartsWith("abc"));
}
```

Comment: Good solution! I needed an easy way to search through the Request.Params NameValueCollection for a specific pattern, and this little tidbit of code helped me get there.

Comment: -1 As covered in the other answers, should be Cast, not OfType, comment and downvote disappears if I see it again and the text doesnt have an OfType in it.

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink , I stand by my use of OfType.  Cast is not reliable, as it has been modified between different .net versions.

Comment: Any citations? What else do you think could be in there? (Obv if this can be confirmed as real then this has real merit and my vote flips)

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/fe6c7c84-5f99-484a-99de-b331d4c88b76/ from Heljsberg: "All of this was fixed in SP1"

Comment: @David B I very much disagree that changes in semantics on the supported value type conversions should prevent one from, in the case of a clear reference type casting requirement, switch from using the `Cast` conversion operator to a filtering predicate which a) conveys a completely different meaning b) could result in stuff silently being ignored - I want that to fail fast. But I very much welcome the response so will now execute vote flip by doing a null edit

Answer (score 8):

A dictionary is probably actually closer to what you want to use since it will actually fill more of the roles that NameValueCollection fills. This is a variation of Bryan Watts' solution:

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static IDictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this NameValueCollection source)
    {
        return source.Cast<string>().Select(s => new { Key = s, Value = source[s] }).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not great. A NameValueCollection is actually roughly `IDictionary<string,IEnumerable<string>>`. For some use cases that should be preserved. `ILookup` is what you really need. Something like `souce.Cast<string>().SelectMany(s => source.GetValues(s).Select(t=> new {Key=s, Value=t}) ).ToLookup(p=>p.Key,p=>p.Value)`. That will play very nicely with Linq, since ILookup was created specifically for Linq.

Comment: -1 This is just a specific impl of @Frans Bouma's impl, with the noted side effect of compacting the values separated by commas. -1 goes when this uses ToLookup

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the collection implements `IEnumerable` (as opposed to `IEnumerable<T>`) and enumerating the collection returns the keys, not the pairs.

If I were you, I'd use a `Dictionary<string, string>` which is enumerable and can be used with LINQ.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite understand why despite that NameValueCollection implements IEnumerable, it still says that source is not IEnumerable.

Comment: It implements IEnumerable (on the base class) but it doesn't implement IEnumerable<T> (the generic variant) so you can't use the extension methods which require the generic variant.

Comment: +1 But as noted by @Kevin Cathcart on Orion Adrian's answer, if you actually flatten to a `Dictionary<key,string>`, multiple values get joined  with a comma which makes the operation lossy

Answer (score 3):

For me, @Bryan Watts' (+1'd) answer's `ToLookup` variant represents by far the clearest approach for using it on a read-only basis.

For my use case, I'm manipulating a query string for use with [Linq2Rest](http://nuget.org/packages/linq2rest) and also need to turn it all back into a `NameValueCollection` at the end, so I have a set of extension methods for `NameValueCollection` which offer more granular operations (to operate both per parameter name (`AsEnumerable`) and per argument (`AsKeyValuePairs`)) and also the inverse operation of converting it back `ToNameValueCollection` (from either representation)).

Example consumption:

```
public static NameValueCollection WithoutPagingOperators( this NameValueCollection that )
{
    return that.AsEnumerable()
        .Where( @param => @param.Key != OdataParameters.Skip 
          && @param.Key != OdataParameters.Top )
        .ToNameValueCollection();
}
```

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;

public static class NamedValueCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> AsEnumerable( this NameValueCollection that )
    {
        return that
            .Cast<string>() // doesn't implement IEnumerable<T>, but does implement IEnumerable
            .Select( ( item, index ) => // enable indexing by integer rather than string
                new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>( item, that.GetValues( index ) ) ); // if you use the indexer or GetValue it flattens multiple values for a key, Joining them with a ',' which we don't want
    }

    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> AsKeyValuePairs( this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> that )
    {
        return that
            .SelectMany( item =>
                item.Value.Select( value =>
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>( item.Key, value ) ) );
    }

    public static NameValueCollection ToNameValueCollection( this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> that )
    {
        return that.AsKeyValuePairs().ToNameValueCollection();
    }

    public static NameValueCollection ToNameValueCollection( this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> that )
    {
        var result = new NameValueCollection();
        foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, string> item in that )
            result.Add( item.Key, item.Value );
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see why anyone would need to add an extension method.
Here's some different ways to do it in VB.NET.  It includes 4 different intermediate forms of IEnumerable: Array, Tuple, Anonymous, and KeyValuePair.  For the C# equivalent go to converter.telerik dot com and convert it.

```
Dim nvc As New NameValueCollection() From {{"E", "55"}, {"A", "11"}, {"D", "44"}, {"C", "33"}, {"G", "66"}, {"B", "22"}}

Dim dictStrings As Dictionary(Of String, String) = nvc.Cast(Of String).ToDictionary(Function(key) key, Function(key) nvc(key))
Dim Ints2Chars__ As Dictionary(Of Integer, Char) = nvc.Cast(Of Object).ToDictionary(Function(key) CInt(nvc(CStr(key))), Function(key) CChar(key))

Dim arrEnumerable__ = From x In nvc.Cast(Of String) Select {x, nvc(x)}
Dim tupleEnumerable = From x In nvc.Cast(Of String) Select Tuple.Create(x, nvc(x))
Dim anonEnumerable_ = From X In nvc.Cast(Of String) Select New With {X, .Y = nvc(X)}
Dim kvpEnumerable__ = From x In nvc.Cast(Of String) Select New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(x, nvc(x))

Dim anonQuery = From anon In anonEnumerable_ Let n = CInt(anon.Y) Order By n Where n > 30 Select New With {.num = n, .val = anon.X}
Dim dictQuery = anonQuery.ToDictionary(Of Integer, String)(Function(o) o.num, Function(o) o.val)


Dim dictArray_ = arrEnumerable__.ToDictionary(Function(x) x(0), Function(x) x(1))
Dim dictTuples = tupleEnumerable.ToDictionary(Function(tuple) tuple.Item1, Function(tuple) tuple.Item2)
Dim dictAnon__ = anonEnumerable_.ToDictionary(Function(anon) anon.X, Function(anon) anon.Y)
Dim dictKVPrs_ = kvpEnumerable__.ToDictionary(Function(kvp) kvp.Key, Function(kvp) kvp.Value)
```