# How do I access query string parameters in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string

I want to have different sorting and filtering applied on my view
I figured that I'll be passing sorting and filtering *params* through query string:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { SortBy= "Name"})
```

This simple construction allows me to sort. View comes back with this in query string:

```
?SortBy=Name
```

Now I want to add filtering and i want my query string to end up with

```
?SortBy=Name&Filter=Something
```

How can I add another parameter to list of already existing ones in `ActionLink`? for Example:

```
user requests /Index/
```

view has

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { SortBy= "Name"})
```

and

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { FilterBy= "Name"})
```

**Links**: The first one looks like `/Index/?SortBy=Name` and The second is  `/Index/?FilterBy=Name`

I want when user pressed sorting link after he applied some filtering - filtering is not lost, so i need a way to combine my params.
My guess is there should be a way to not parse query string, but get collection of parameters from some MVC object.

Comment: How about a razor syntax update to the question?

Comment: there you go.. only took me 4 years.. (-:

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Use-querystring-variables-in-Asp-Net-MVC-controller

Answer (score 30, accepted):

so far the best way I figured out is to create a copy of `ViewContext.RouteData.Values`
and inject QueryString values into it.
and then modify it before every `ActionLink` usage.
still trying to figure out how to use `.Union()` instead of modifying a dictionary all the time.

```
<% RouteValueDictionary   tRVD = new RouteValueDictionary(ViewContext.RouteData.Values); %>

<% foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys )
    {
         tRVD[key]=Request.QueryString[key].ToString();
    } %>

<%tRVD["SortBy"] = "Name"; %>
                <%= Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", tRVD)%>
```

Comment: Another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391023/make-namevaluecollection-accessible-to-linq-query/396504) indicates that this is be best way when using `@Html.ActionLink`. I setteled for `<a href="Index?@Request.QueryString">Name</a>`.

Comment: Any better way of doing this using ASP.NET MVC 3 or 4?

Comment: @LenielMacaferi, View models

Answer (score 12):

My solution is similar to qwerty1000's.  I created an extension method, `ActionQueryLink`, that takes in the same basic parameters as the standard `ActionLink`.  It loops through Request.QueryString and adds any parameters found to the `RouteValues` dictionary that are not already present (so we can overwrite the original query string if needed).

To preserve the existing string but not add any keys the usage would be:

```
<%= Html.ActionQueryLink("Click Me!","SomeAction") %>
```

To preserve the existing string and add new keys the user would be:

```
<%= Html.ActionQueryLink("Click Me!","SomeAction", new{Param1="value1", Param2="value2"} %>
```

The code below is for the two usages, but it should be pretty easy to add other overloads to match the other `ActionLink` extensions as needed.

```
    public static string ActionQueryLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        string linkText, string action)
    {
        return ActionQueryLink(htmlHelper, linkText, action, null);
    }

    public static string ActionQueryLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string linkText, string action, object routeValues)
    {
        var queryString =
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

        var newRoute = routeValues == null 
            ? htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values 
            : new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);

        foreach (string key in queryString.Keys)
        {
            if (!newRoute.ContainsKey(key)) 
                newRoute.Add(key, queryString[key]);
        }
        return HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext,
            htmlHelper.RouteCollection, linkText, null /* routeName */, 
            action, null, newRoute, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { SortBy= "Name", Filter="Something"}) %>
```

To preserve the querystring you can:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", 
     String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["SortBy"]) ? 
        new { Filter = "Something" } : 
        new { SortBy=Request.QueryString["SortBy"], Filter="Something"}) %>
```

Or if you have more parameters, you could build the link manually by using taking `Request.QueryString` into account.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ActionLinkCombined` instead of `ActionLink`

```
        public static string ActionLinkCombined(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName,
                                            object routeValues)
    {
        var dictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
        foreach (var pair in htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider)
            dictionary[pair.Key] = pair.Value.AttemptedValue;
        if (routeValues != null)
        {
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(routeValues))
            {
                object o = descriptor.GetValue(routeValues);
                dictionary[descriptor.Name] = o;
            }
        }
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, dictionary);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**MVC4**

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text","action",new { @id = 5, @name = "textName", @abc = "abc" })
```

***OR***

```
 @Html.ActionLink("link text", "action", "controller", new { @id = 5, @name = "textName", @abc = "abc" }, new { @class = "cssClass" })
```

querystring would be like:

```
yourDomainRout/action/5?name=textName&abc=abc
```

it would have `class="cssClass"`

Comment: see this line `new { @id = 5, @name = "textName", @abc = "abc" }` why you use @ sign many times. @ sign is used for reserved keyword.