# mvc 2 passing a parameter as a QueryString

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, query-string, redirecttoaction, querystringparameter

If I have for example a controller home with a ActionResult videoInfo **Home/VideoInfo** that pop up a form where put id and after clicking button **getinfo** it will redirect me to a page where info about a video are displayed. VideoInfo is an **ActionResult**.
The url look like: **Home/VideoInfo/21222** where 21222 is the id and this url display some infos about a video. For the **Id** I have created a model : **class Video** with the property **public int id {get; set}.**

**How** can I make the url **home/VideoInfo?id=21222** and redirect me to a page where info's are dispayed? make it like a querystring i guess..., no?

Need help pls. Thx

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/594019/2291 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/968904/2291