# How to traverse through Request.Form without knowing any details?

Tags: c#, asp.net, request.form

I want to spit out everything in Request.Form so I can just return it as a string and see what I am dealing with. I tried setting up a for loop...

```
// Order/Process
// this action is the submit POST from the pricing options selection page
// it consumes the pricing options, creates a new order in the database,
// and passes the user off to the Edit view for payment information collection

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public string Process()
{
    string posted = "";
    for(int n = 0;n < Request.Form.Count;n++)
        posted += Request.Form[n].ToString();
    return posted;
}
```

But all I ever get back is '12' and I know there are a lot more things on the form than that...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
{
    s.AppendLine(key + ": " + Request.Form[key]);
}
string formData = s.ToString();
```

Answer (score 10):

```
foreach(string key in Request.Form.Keys)
{
  posted += Request.Form[key].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

OHHH I figured out my problem, in my form the one value that I keep getting back is from the only input control that has a NAME. Now that I give them names, it is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in Request.Form){
   posted += kvp.Key + ":" + kvp.Value + "\n";
}
```

Edit: Oh. Apparently you have to [hack the NameValueCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391023/make-namevaluecollection-accessible-to-linq-query) to get it to do this. So this is a bad way to iterate over the collection.