# C# Iterate through NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, collections, namevaluecollection

I have a `NameValueCollection`, and want to iterate through the values.  Currently, I’m doing this, but it seems like there should be a neater way to do it:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("Test", "Val1");
nvc.Add("Test2", "Val1");
nvc.Add("Test2", "Val1");
nvc.Add("Test2", "Val2");
nvc.Add("Test3", "Val1");
nvc.Add("Test4", "Val4");

foreach (string s in nvc)
    foreach (string v in nvc.GetValues(s))
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", s, v);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Is there?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it per se - just that I thought I should be able to iterate using a single loop.  Looking at the answers so far, this doesn't seem to be possible if there may be duplicate key values.

Comment: that's correct, but you can use different collection e.g. `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391023/make-namevaluecollection-accessible-to-linq-query

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can flatten the collection with Linq, but it's still a `foreach` loop but now more implicit.

```
var items = nvc.AllKeys.SelectMany(nvc.GetValues, (k, v) => new {key = k, value = v});
foreach (var item in items)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.key, item.value);
```

The first line, converts the nested collection to a (non-nested) collection of anonymous objects with the properties *key* and *value*.

It's flatten in the way that it's now a mapping *key -> value* instead of *key -> collection of values*. The example data:

Before:

> Test -> [Val],
>
> Test2 -> [Val1, Val1, Val2],
>
> Test3 -> [Val1],
>
> Test4 -> [Val4]

After:

> Test -> Val,
>
> Test2 -> Val1,
>
> Test2 -> Val1,
>
> Test2 -> Val2,
>
> Test3 -> Val1,
>
> Test4 -> Val4

Comment: Tested and using `using System.Linq;`

Comment: In case someone wants to know the vb.net syntax: `Dim items = nvc.AllKeys.SelectMany(AddressOf col.GetValues, Function(k, v) New With {.key = k, .value = v})`

Comment: @EndyTjahjono slight typo, change "col" to "nvp" so it becomes `Dim items = nvc.AllKeys.SelectMany(AddressOf nvp.GetValues, Function(k, v) New With {.key = k, .value = v})`

Comment: [Wouldn't `v` simply refer to the index of the current key?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549142(v=vs.100).aspx#parameters)

Comment: What if it's a blank value, how do I just get add `string.empty` instead?

Comment: what is a blank value? `null`?

Comment: Alternatively: `nvc.AllKeys.Select(k => $"{k}={nvc[k]}")`. Formats as a key and its comma-separated values.

Comment: This way is too inefficient! using AllKeys, SelectMany, GetValues, Creating new anonym/dynamic object.... too much to just enumerate a simple collection!

Answer (score 98):

You can use the key for lookup instead of having two loops:

```
foreach (string key in nvc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", key, nvc[key]);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will behave differently to the OP's code if there are any keys with multiple values. Your code will output *"key value1,value2,value3"*, whereas the OP's code would output *"key value1"* then *"key value2"* then *"key value3"*.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing new to see here (@Julian's +1'd by me answer is functionally equivalent), y'all move along y'all please.

---

I have an [overkill for this case but possibly relevant] set of extension methods [in an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12709084/11635), which would let you do:

```
foreach ( KeyValuePair<string,string> item in nvc.AsEnumerable().AsKeyValuePairs() )
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.key, item.value);
```

Comment: NameValueCollection does not have AsEnumerable or as keyValuePairs

Comment: @Luis Tellez. I know. The text says **I have a set of extension methods**. And it links to it. And the body text is flagging that there is nothing new to see here please. Does this clarify or do I need to re-explain?

Comment: You can make an enumerable as `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> e = nvc.AllKeys.Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k, nvc[k]))`. Another stumbling point brought to you by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

```
var enu = myNameValueCollection.GetEnumerator();
while (enu.MoveNext())
{
    string key = (string)enu.Current;
    string value = myNameValueCollection[key];
}
```

OR when keys nullable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myNameValueCollection.Count; i++)
{
    string key = myNameValueCollection.GetKey(i);
    string value = myNameValueCollection.Get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to avoid the nested loops is using additional List to store the values:

```
List<string> arrValues = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < nvc.Count; i++)
    arrValues.AddRange(nvc.GetValues(i));
foreach (string value in arrValues)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
```

(Requires [only] .NET 2.0 or later)

Comment: (obviously superseded by using `SelectMany` like [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5066541/11635))

Comment: @Ruben true, but I prefer to leave this one even if just for historical value showing how to do that with old .NET version. :)

Comment: The thing with `SelectMany` i came across is if the key has a value that's blank it fails. Any way around it? Thanks.

Comment: @Si8 what exactly fails? In theory, just throw an `if` statement and check for null, though if your code is one-liner, it will make it much less readable.

Comment: Your method works with the null but the LINQ doesn't is what I was stating... sorry for not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simpler:   VB.NET

```
For i As Integer = 0 To nvc.Count - 1
   Console.Write("No", "Key", "Value")
   Console.Write(i, nvc.GetKey(i), nvc.Get(i))
Next
```

C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= nvc.Count - 1; i++)
{
    Console.Write("No", "Key", "Value");
    Console.Write(i, nvc.GetKey(i), nvc.Get(i));
}
```

Comment: This is the worst C# I've ever seen.

Comment: Sorry, I think in vb.net! Updated

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nvc.Count; i++) {
    System.Console.WriteLine(

        nvc.AllKeys[i] + " = " + nvc[i]

    );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach ( string key in nvc.Keys )
   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", key, nvc[key]);
```

This will return you all keys and corresponding values.

Comment: No; it won't return duplicate values.

Comment: Isnt this a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/a/5065986/11635 which is milliseconds earlier (wow!) - personally I'd delete. @Slaks to be pedantic, it will give the duplicate values, just with commas separating them.