# foreach KeyValuePair in NameValueCollection?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
NameValueCollection nv = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);        
foreach (KeyValuePair<String,String> pr in nv) {
    //process KeyValuePair          
}
```

This compiles, but when I try to run it I get an `InvalidCastException`.

Why is this? Why can't I use `KeyValuePair` to iterate over a `NameValueCollection`, and what should I use instead?

Comment: I like this as I can init a dictionary without having to create a backing dictionary variable in addition to a foreach. `var nv = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
    var qsDic = nv.Cast<object>().ToDictionary<object, string, object>(key => (string) key, key => nv[(string) key]);`

Answer (score 144, accepted):

First of all, `NameValueCollection` doesn't use `KeyValuePair<String,String>`. Also, `foreach` only exposes the key:

```
NameValueCollection nv = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);        
foreach (string key in nv) {
    var value = nv[key];

}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's kind of weird. I would have expected there to be a way to get both at once.

Comment: We all do when we start using a NVC.

Comment: Was wondering how to do this... thanks! Btw, you don't need to specify `KeyValuePair<String,String>` as the NameValueCollection only uses string,string. No need to specify it.

Comment: If you want more control, you can create your own object (which holds a key and a value) and put it in a list, then foreach on your object.

Comment: ehh? I said that the NVC do not use KeyValuePair?

Comment: Be aware how this code functions for duplicate keys. When duplicate keys exist, it will return "key value1,value2,value3", instead of "key value1" then "key value2" then "key value3".

Comment: This new way seems dumb. I'd really like to know why this is used instead of say a Dictionary so that we could use KeyValuePair. In other words what problem(s) does NameValueCollection solve over Dictionary?

Comment: @Nick: NameValueCollection is one of the first collection types in .NET. It's case insensitive and merge existing values (which is useful for some protocols)

Comment: This solution will not work as expected if you have duplicate keys (NameValueCollection supports duplicate keys). Use Endy Tjahjono's solution instead.

Answer (score 14):

You can't do that directly, but you can create an extension method like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> AsKVP(
        this NameValueCollection source
)
{
    return source.AllKeys.SelectMany(
        source.GetValues,
        (k, v) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k, v));
}
```

Then you can do:

```
NameValueCollection nv = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
foreach (KeyValuePair<String,String> pr in nv.AsKVP()) {
    //process KeyValuePair          
}
```

Note: inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5066541/196451). SelectMany is required to handle duplicate keys.

vb.net version:

```
<Extension>
Public Function AsKVP(
        source As Specialized.NameValueCollection
) As IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
    Dim result = source.AllKeys.SelectMany(
        AddressOf source.GetValues,
        Function(k, v) New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(k, v))
    Return result
End Function
```

Answer (score 10):

For future reference, you could also use this syntax:

```
foreach(string key in Request.QueryString)
{
    var value = Request.QueryString[key];
}
```

Comment: Well. If you got access to the `HttpRequest` you can skip `AllKeys` as the `QueryString` property is a `NameValueCollection`.

Comment: -1 because you don't have to use `AllKeys` as @jgauffin mentioned

Comment: @Warlock: Giving a -1 for that is a bit harsh. You can edit the answer, can't you?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, I didn't want to hurt anybody :) But the problem was not only in the property. If you look at the @jgauffin's answer, he proposed the same idea, but it was posted earlier. So, this post looks like a duplication.

Comment: If you look at the last comment it's written by me `jgauffin` and the answers are not duplicates if you look closer.

Comment: Cool :) But I still can't see the difference. The same `NameValueCollection` with the same `foreach`. Your answer is more complete btw.

Comment: My answer can parse any string while his uses a already parsed query string. imho his answer works better when wanting the query from the current http request.

Answer (score 6):

ANother extension method, for learning purposes:

```
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ToIEnumerable(this NameValueCollection nvc)
    {
        foreach (string key in nvc.AllKeys)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, nvc[key]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice solution! I would just suggest to use `nvc` instead of `nvc.AllKeys`. I'm wondering why Microsoft guys didn't add this in `System.Linq`. :)

Answer (score 2):

NameValueCollection uses the old-skool enumerator:

```
        var enu = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetEnumerator();

        while(enu.MoveNext())
        {
            string key = (string)enu.Current;
            string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like this and it works:

```
 foreach (string akey in request.Query.Keys.Cast<string>())
     writer.WriteLine(akey + " = " + request.Query[akey]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the key name might appear more than once in the query string and that the comparison is usually case sensitive.
If you want to just get the value of the first matching key and not bothered about case then use this:

```
        public string GetQueryValue(string queryKey)
        {
            foreach (string key in QueryItems)
            {
                if(queryKey.Equals(key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    return QueryItems.GetValues(key).First(); // There might be multiple keys of the same name, but just return the first match
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert nameValueCollection from QueryString to List you can use extension like this:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetParams(this HttpRequest request)
{
    var nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.QueryString.Value);
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyValueCollections = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    if (!nameValueCollection.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        foreach (var key in nameValueCollection.AllKeys)
        {
            keyValueCollections.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, nameValueCollection[key]));
        }
    }
    return keyValueCollections;
}
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

How about using the built in `.AsEnumerable()` extension method? Example:

```cs
NameValueCollection nv = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);        
foreach (KeyValuePair<String,String> pr in nv.AsEnumerable()) {
    //process KeyValuePair          
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void PrintKeysAndValues2( NameValueCollection myCol )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "   [INDEX] KEY        VALUE" );
    for ( int i = 0; i < myCol.Count; i++ )
        Console.WriteLine( "   [{0}]     {1,-10} {2}", i, myCol.GetKey(i), myCol.Get(i) );
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx

Comment: -1 You show that it is possible to use for to access `NameValueCollection` data. But the question is why you cannot convert `NameValueCollection` items to `KeyValuePair<string, string>`. Maybe you read the question not very carefully. The best answer was given by `jgauffin`. An interesting solution was proposed by `Adrian Carneiro`.